# PIP RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.4

I have been trying to install PIP on my python 3.4.0 on windows but none of the solutions work. I have tried python get-pip.py pip==19.1 and getting get-pip.py from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.4/get-pip.py. I have also tried using pip3.4.exe and pip.exe in the python folder.

```
C:\Python34>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 21478, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 119, in bootstrap
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Python 3.5 or later is required")
RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required
```

Comment: Why not update to the latest version of Python?

Comment: Note that python3.4 already hit end of life. I recommend at least going to Python3.8 https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches

Comment: I use python 3.4 because there's cx freeze. Basically, if I code in python 3.4, I would have the option of freezing it into an executable

Comment: Do you have pip installed already?

Comment: No, I'm trying to install it

Comment: cx freeze supports newer python versions

Comment: Wait really? How can I set it up?